# Passing a Stack to a method

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, stack

What is the proper way to pass a Stack to a method? I'm getting an error saying my method call has some invalid arguments.

```
string userInput = inputText.Text;
Stack<double> numbers= new Stack<double>();
Stack<char> operators = new Stack<char>();
bool output;

output = calculateExpression(userInput, Stack<double> numbers, Stack<char> operators);
```

My definition:

```
double calculateExpression(string userInput, Stack<double> numbers, Stack<char> operators)
{}
```

Comment: You can't assign a double to a bool. Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the types in the function call:

```
output = calculateExpression(userInput, numbers, operators);
```

I also noticed that your function returns a double but you are assigning it to a bool.
You can fix this problem with by changing the output var type like:

```
double output;
```

and

```
 double calculateExpression(string userInput, Stack<double> numbers, Stack<char> operators)
    {}
```

or by changing the function return value like:

```
bool calculateExpression(string userInput, Stack<double> numbers, Stack<char> operators)
{}
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I tried removing the types... You're correct. Thank you. Will accept your answer once it allows me in 10 min. Thanks again for the speedy response!

Comment: Appreciated! Simple things can be easy to overlook.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, that was a typo. I added that to limit the context of the problem. I'm actually sending it to a asp.net label. So I still have to convert the output to a string.